# How to install the eclipse source code via "Eclipse Marketplace" or "Install New Software" option from eclipse menu?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing Eclipse RCP application, I am very new in RCP development & plugins development. I want to attach the eclipse source code in my eclipse (Kepler 4.3.2).
Please suggest me step by step, how to attach the source code in my current eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'Help > Install New Software...'

In 'Work with' enter the updates site for your release. This is `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3` for Eclipse Kepler (4.3), `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5` for the more current Eclipse Mars (4.5).

Select and install 'Eclipse Platform SDK' for the core source, or 'Eclipse SDK' for more complete source.

Once this is installed open the 'Preferences' and go to the 'Plug-in Development' page. Check the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option. This will include the source in Eclipse searches and the 'Open Type' dialog. Note: If you are using a 'Target Platform' the source need to be included in the target platform to get the search to work.

Alternatively most of the downloads from the [Eclipse Projects page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) include the source plugins.