# In which eclipse project Tasks View code present

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am not able to find eclipse project which contains source code for Tasks view.
I search many eclipse project from below URL
https://projects.eclipse.org/
But not able to find project which contains Tasks View source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks view `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.TasksView` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin which is part of the core Eclipse Platform project.

The GIT source for Platform is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles). You can also install the source in to your Eclipse by installing the Eclipse Platform SDK.

Comment: Thanks for answer I found the class. How can i install the source in Eclipse. Do you have any manual for that. I want to use eclipse feature as well as want to debug functionality.  Like Task View in eclipse i want to add TODO task in java file and want to debug how eclipse IDE add that TODO task into Task view.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719002/2670892) covers installing the source.

Comment: You could always just ask a question here about what the Tasks view displays.