# How to search all Git repositories of the Eclipse Foundation?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to fix a bug in the Eclipse IDE. I guess the problem is somewhere in either platform or UI. My goal is to find the code where the issue could be.

The Eclipse Foundation hosts its git repositories at https://git.eclipse.org. But there are way too many repositories to even know where to look.

Is there some way to search the whole source code of all those repositories? Like an OpenGrok instance or the now defunct grepcode?

Comment: You can have the source code of the Eclipse you are actually using installed in Eclipse (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719002/2670892)). You can then read the source in Eclipse or debug Eclipse directly rather than trying to search the GIT repositories.

Comment: You can do a web search with `site:git.eclipse.org/c/platform/ <class, package, etc.>`. But I would recommend using [PDE](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/) to run and debug the Eclipse IDE. In PDE you can get the code via _File > Import...: Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments_ direct from Git repository (all or at least most Eclipse plug-ins knows their Git repository location).

Comment: @greg-449 I tried it but the source seems to be incomplete. For example I tried to show references to org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants.EDITOR_MARK_OCCURRENCES. That only shows the class itself, although it is used at least in ToggleMarkOccurrencesAction

Comment: @howlger As an example I tried to do a web search in Google for EDITOR_MARK_OCCURRENCES but it does not find the source for ToggleMarkOccurrencesAction, so the index seems to be incomplete as well.

Comment: To not restrict it to the platform only and to include also JDT do a web search with `site:git.eclipse.org/c/ "EDITOR_MARK_OCCURRENCES"`.

Comment: The source is complete but you can't do searches for Java constant references because they are inlined by the compiler so the search can't see them. This is a general problem with Java code searches.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the reply, but at least for me Google does not find ToggleMarkOccurrencesAction with that query.

Comment: @greg-449 I think this is only a problem with binary dependencies. I use it all the time in my big multi project structure and it works fine. I guess I would need the source checked out as a project for that to work.

Comment: Yes that is correct, if the source code is in the workspace constants searches work, but if the code is in jars with a source attachment it doesn't work because the search looks at the .class files rather than the source attachment.

Comment: [DuckDuckGo finds also `ToggleMarkOccurrencesAction`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Agit.eclipse.org%2Fc+%22ToggleMarkOccurrencesAction%22&t=h_&ia=web). But I would recommend using the Java and the Plug-in search. Make sure you have added all plug-ins to the search (in the _Plug-ins_ view select all plug-ins (Ctrl+A), right-click and choose _Add to Java Search_). To be able to edit a plug-in you have to import it (_File > Import...: Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments_).